# How does a Model know what migration it is associated with?

Tags: php, laravel, model, database-migration

I apologize for the noob question. I am coming from the frontend and trying to improve my development skills by learning the backend. I am fairly new to PHP. I am having a hard time understanding how a Model knows which Migration it is associated with and vice versa? For example, how does a Model class know what table to write data to?

Comment: It is based on convention unless specified explicitly  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class:

```
// Copied from the framework.
namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

abstract class Model implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess, Jsonable, JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable
{

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table;

    /**
     * Get the table associated with the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->table ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this)));
    }
}
```

So if the `$table` instance variable is not set, the database table name to interact with will be calculated using the class name.